# JSON Deserialization in C# comparison

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have never worked before with JSON data. I'm trying to deserialize the following line:

`{"Mails":[null,{"ID":"ulasdas@gmail.com","Status":true},{"ID":"ADSsdasA@ONO.COM","Status":false}]}`

I'm using the following code but it's not working:

```
public Boolean checkValidLicense(string usermail)
{
    Boolean validUser = false;

    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://popping-heat-1908.firebaseio.com/.json") as HttpWebRequest;
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

        dynamic result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        foreach (var item in result.Mails)
        {
            if (usermail == item.ID && item.Status == "true") 
            {
                validUser = true;
                break;
             }

        }

        return validUser;
    }
```

I'm getting:

> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'ID'.

Comment: Could you create a typed model and use the generic (`<T>`) API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not deserialize to `dynamic` type unless you have a strong reason to do so. Instead, create a type to deserialize to. A great tool for that is [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), though you may often need to make minor adjustments for things it can't infer. Below, we've made two classes. `Mail` represents the individual items, and `MailCollection` is the root JSON object we're deserializing from, which simply contains a collection of `Mail` objects.

```
public class Mail
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

//This is the root object, it's going to hold a collection of the mail
public class MailCollection
{
    public List<Mail> Mails { get; set; }
}

//we pass a type parameter telling it what type to deserialize to
MailCollection result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailCollection>(json);
foreach (var item in result.Mails)
{
    if (usermail == item.ID && item.Status) //since item.Status is a bool, don't compare to a string.
    {
        validUser = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an incredibly useful tool that not many know of directly included in Visual Studio itself! Copy the JSON in the clipboard, then go to a C# code file, then _Edit_ -> _Paste special_ -> _Paste JSON as classes_.
Works really well most of the time and can do the same with XML, adding attributes for serialization and all.

Comment: @Gimly I don't have VS fired up right now. What version does that require, and does it require any special tools such as Mads Kristensen's Web Extensions?

Comment: Not sure about which version started this, but at least it is present in 2012 onward. And it's built-in, no special tools, directly in bare VS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first value of the response you are getting is `null`. This is the result you are getting from the request:

```
{
  "Mails": [
    null,
    {
      "ID": "ulrickpspg@gmail.com",
      "Status": true
    },
    {
      "ID": "ADSA@ONO.COM",
      "Status": false
    }
  ]
}
```

So change the line:

```
if (usermail == item.ID && item.Status == "true")
```

To the line:

```
if (item.Value != null && usermail == item.ID && item.Status == "true")
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue the OP has? You´re simply copying the response that he already posted.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the null element from the beggining?

Comment: Is it a one off or is all your json in that format? @Aldridge1991

Answer (score -2):

1. You need to represent an object for the JSON to comprehend.

### Usings

```
    using System.IO;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

### Object

```
    [JsonObject]
    public class MailItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Boolean Status { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public String SomethingToNotInclude { get; set; }
    }
```

### Get

2. Build a json class to interact with creating, adding, editing and removing.  First we need to Deserialize the json into `List<MailItems>`:

   ```
   private String path = "pathTo.json";
   public List<MailItem> GetMailItems()
   {
       if (!File.Exists(path))
           File.WriteAllText(path, "[]"); //returns an empty list

       String json = File.ReadAllText(path);
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MailItem>>(json);
   }
   ```

### Add

3. When Serializing, I get a full list of the json, then add the object `MailItems` to List, then serialize the list into json and finally write the json to a file.

   ```
   public void AddMailItem(MailItem mailItem)
   {
       String json = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
       List<MailItem> mailItemList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MailItem>>(json);
           if (mailItemList == null)
               mailItemList = new List<MailItem>();
       mailItemList.Add(mailItem);
       String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mailItemList, Formatting.Indented);
       File.WriteAllText(json);
   }
   ```

### Edit

4. When updating an existing item:

   ```
   public void EditMailItem(MailItem mailItem)
   {
       String jsonRead = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
       List<MailItem> mailItemList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MailItem>>(jsonRead);
       int indexOfMailItem = mailItemList.FindIndex(o => o.ID == mailItem.ID); //LINQ
       mailItemList[indexOfMailItem] = mailItem;
       String jsonWrite = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mailItemList, Formatting.Indented);
       File.WriteAllText(jsonWrite);
   }
   ```

Comment: `List<Mails> mailsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Log>>(json);` What is `Log`? Why is `Mails` plural when it only represents one `Mail` object? Why are you deserializing a JSON object into a C# collection?